# How to create 2 sas datasets containing the avg of a previous one

Tags: sas

```
proc sort data = group;
     by studystyle;
run;
proc means data= group mean;
     var test1 test2;
     by studystyle;
     output out = groupmeans mean = groupmeans;
run;
```

so I have this dataset of groups of students containing student ID, test1 scores, test2 scores, and their study styles.

I then created a new dataset of the means of these test scores sorted by the study styles.

I am trying to create 2 new datasets based around the 2 tests, both datasets should include the study style, the mean, and test #.

I figure I can just start by creating a new dataset using the set command to use the previous dataset. However I don't really know how to grab the test means for each study style. instead i just used datalines to manually place the mean values in, however I would prefer to grab those values from the previous dataset itself.

```
data newgroup1;
 set groupmeans;
 drop test1 test2 _type_ _freq_ _stat_;
 input StudyStyle AVG Testnum;
datalines;
 1 51.6875 1
 2 49.27273 1
 3 49.09091 1 
 ;
run;

data newgroup2;
 set groupmeans;
 drop test2 test1 _type_ _freq_ _stat_;
 input StudyStyle AVG Testnum;
datalines;
 1 51.5 2
 2 65.2727 2
 3 90.5454 2
;
run;

data newgroup;
 set newgroup1 newgroup2;
run;
```

Comment: https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/add_average_value_to_dataset

Comment: @Reeza ... is that your github? You should save SAS scripts with extensions: **.sas** to get the nicely colored sas code format: [example](https://github.com/ParfaitG/RANDOM_DATA/blob/master/RandomData.sas).

Comment: @mohb...please show data example to clarify your needs.

Comment: I don't have a github, I just copied the specific lines of code within my SAS program I could use some advice on.

Comment: @Parfait thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @mohb do you have an answer to your question now?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, all you need to change is to create the means of test1 and test2 separately and then write two datasets. Try the code below.

```
proc sort data = group;
by studystyle;
run;

proc means data= group mean;
var test1 test2;
by studystyle;
output out = groupmeans mean(test1) = mtest1 mean(test2) = mtest2;
run;

data newgroup1 (keep=studystyle mtest1) newgroup2(keep=studystyle mtest2) ;
set groupmeans;
run;
```